# flex C exec file

Tags: c, apache-flex, file, exec

is there any way to execute C language executable file from Flex?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine this is not possible. Would you like it if some random Flash banner ran `deltree /Y C:` or `rm -rf /` for you?  However, you can [talk with Javascript](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/External+Interface).

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex to call a php file via HTTPService. The php file will contain something like

```
<?php
shell_exec('./yourExecutable');
?
```

Hope this helps..